# Combine query to get all the matching search text in right order

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, indexing, full-text-search

I have the following table:

```
postgres=# \d so_rum;
                        Table "public.so_rum"
  Column   |          Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id        | integer                 |           |          | 
 title     | character varying(1000) |           |          | 
 posts     | text                    |           |          | 
 body      | tsvector                |           |          | 
 parent_id | integer                 |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "so_rum_body_idx" rum (body)
```

I wanted to do phrase search query, so I came up with the below query, for example:

```
select id from so_rum
    where body @@ phraseto_tsquery('english','Is it possible to toggle the visibility');
```

This gives me the results, which only match's the entire text. However, there are documents, where the distance between lexmes are more and the above query doesn't gives me back those data.  For example: `'it is something possible to do toggle between the. . .  visibility'` doesn't get returned. I know I can get it returned with `<2>` (for example) distance operator by giving in the `to_tsquery`, manually.

But I wanted to understand, how to do this in my sql statement itself, so that I get the results  first with distance of `1` and then `2` and so on (may be till `6-7`). Finally append results with the actual count of the search words like the following query:

```
select count(id) from so_rum
    where body @@ to_tsquery('english','string & string . . . ')
```

Is it possible to do in a single query with good performance?

Comment: It sounds like you want a full text search:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html.

Comment: Yes. The query above is actually doing the full text search.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a canned solution to this.  It sounds like you need to use plainto_tsquery to get all the results with all the lexemes, and then implement your own custom ranking function to rank them by distance between the lexemes, and maybe filter out ones with the wrong order.